# Sum of specific key-value in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `school` dictionary as follow-

```
{
    ID('6a15ce'): {
        'count': 5,
        'amount': 0,
        'r_amount': None,
        'sub': < subobj >
    }, ID('464ba1'): {
        'count': 2,
        'amount': 120,
        'r_amount': None,
        'sub': < subobj2 >
    }
}
```

I want to find out the sum of `amount`  , doing as follow-

`{k:sum(v['amount']) for k,v in school.items()}`

but here I am getting error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` what could be efficient way to achieve.

Comment: What is `ID()`?  This just isn't a valid python dictionary.

Comment: @chrisz, why? `ID` may be some class or a function.

Comment: @ForceBru `ID` could be, but < subobj2 > is not.  Unless I guess this is the output of a print statement rather than the definition.

Comment: @Prashant, did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask further questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
result = sum(v["amount"] for v in school.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the `map` function:

```
result = sum(map(lambda i: i['amount'], school.values()))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
120
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = sum(map(itemgetter('amount'), school.values()))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sum(map(lambda schoolAmount: schoolAmount.amount, school))
```